# Webup8team Oracle JDK 9 removes OpenJDK 9

Tags: java, dependencies, openjdk, oracle

I try to install **OpenJDK 9** and **Oracle JDK 9** in the same **Ubuntu 17.10** machine, but looks like both are exclusive packages.

If I have installed OpenJDK 9 and try to install the Oracle one, apt is removing OpenJDK 9.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jre-headless
```

It is not happening the same for OpenJDK 8 and Oracle JDK 8. I have both installed without any problem.

I'm pretty sure that there is a good reason for this. so this is the question: What is the reason because it is not possible to install both OpenJDK 9 and Oracle JDK 9 in the same machine?